# Word Wrap adds blank line when printing excel sheet due to Page Layout adding additional pixels in width

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013

When I try to *print preview* or look at the *Page Layout* (or print) an excel sheet, it changes my column width.  I noticed the change is by around 5 pixels.  This change is good enough to cause below issue:

In below screenshot you can see "Real Estate Taxes" expands height of *Row32* due to *word wrap* turned on for that cell.  However, when I print the worksheet, it is able to fit "Real Estate Taxes" in original row height and leaves rest of the space blank even though *word wrap* is turned on.

How do I either prevent *word wrap* issue or make sure *Page Layout* does not change my column width automatically?  I am novice in excel, but I know it has something to do with "Scaling".  I am not able to figure out how to prevent this.

Note:  Data below is generated from a pivot table.

[image]

Comment: I think the reason that you aren't getting the results you were hoping for (which would be answers to your question) is because you asked the question on the wrong site. I am sorry that this wasn't closed/migrated to the appropriate site ([su]) before you posted a bounty, and that is our fault.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.  I will ask the question at Super User.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sheet Setup]

2) Make column a fair amount wider by dragging the right boundary of the column heading.
[image: Make column a fair amount wider]

3) Double-click row separator to auto fit the row height.

[image: Auto fit the row height]

4) Double-click column separator to auto fit the column width.

[image: Future automatic width adjustment is different based on when the "wrap text" formatting was applied]

Note:  Notice the effect of adding additional text to the cells. The result of future automatic width adjustment is different based on when the "wrap text" formatting was applied, before or after the adjustments to the width & height of the cell(s).

[image]